# issue with CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE

Tags: android

Is it necessary to use "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" permission to work "CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" reciver?
When I test it with "INTERNET" permission and not "ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" works like a charm.
Any idea or comment will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

android.permission.INTERNET
Allows applications to open network sockets

&&

android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
Allows applications to access information about networks

It do requires the caller to hold the permission ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE